# django - click the button and save create date in database

Tags: django, database, date, button, click

Database:
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFBPp.png)
Model :

```
class Donor(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    bloodType = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    createdDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    lastAttendance = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

View:

```
donor_id = None
if request.method == "GET":
    donor_id = request.GET['id']

if donor_id:
    donor = Donor.objects.get(id=int(donor_id))
    if donor:
        donor.createdDate = True
        donor.save()
```

> Error message: MultiValueDictKeyError at /donors/
>   "'id'"

Problem:
[approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI0Mm.png)
Click the attentd button, take user's id and save in the database current date.
Any solutions appreciated!!

Comment: Can you include with your url.py and relevant html code on with that `attend` button ?

Comment: **url**
url(r'^donors/$', views.donors,  name='donors'),

**html**
<td><form action="get">
<button type="submit" class="btn attendBtn"  id="{{ item.id }}" name="attend">attend</button>
</form></td>

Comment: Did you pass `item` object to template ?

Comment: ** like that **

{% for item in query_results %}
       <tr> 
        <td id="appointment_id" class="hidden">{{ item.id }}</td>
           <td>{{ item.firstName }}</td>
           <td>{{ item.lastName }}</td>
           <td>{{ item.bloodType }}</td>
           <td>{{ item.createdDate|date:"d M Y" }}</td>
           <td></td>
           <td><form action="get"><button type="submit" class="btn attendBtn"  id="{{ item.id }}" name="attend">attend</button></form></td>
       </tr>
       {% endfor %}

Comment: I made the answer. Can you check it now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add value in button so you can get value as GET parameter.

```
<form action="get">
  <button 
    type="submit" 
    class="btn attendBtn" 
    value="{{ item.id }}" 
    name="attend">attend
  </button>
 </form>
```

Normally in input buttons we don't specify value attribute, It's because user entered value and submit the button for processing. But in your case we need to declare explicitly value.

Comment: yeah, it's working : http://127.0.0.1:8000/donors/get?attend=2

(2 is an id )
I just have to add another parameter with date, so it will save current date

Comment: Okay. Please accept this answer as well. Let the community know this answer works for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if request.method == "GET":
    donor_id = request.GET.get('id')
```

`request.GET['key']` would raise a `KeyError` if the key doesn't exist.

`request.GET.get('key', '')` allows us to specify a default value, if the key is not available. If omitted, the default value is ''. So, it won't raise error, if there is no id in the request.GET

Answer (score 0):

Use the MultiValueDict's get method. This is also present on standard dicts and is a way to fetch a value while providing a default if it does not exist.

```
donor_id = request.GET.get('id', False)
Generally,

my_var = dict.get(<key>, <default>)
```